# erlang shell can't ping pong in same pc

Tags: erl

when I use erl open multi nodes,
and then I start erl like this:

```
erl -sname test1
erl -sname test2
```

And then, I logon the two shells and test ping each other,
but can't ping pong.

```
net_adm:ping(test2).
```

Anywhere wrong? Does somebody know?
The detail message info is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNzKX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Once you issued `erl -sname [some_name]` check inside your shell what the name of the node is , using the method  `node/0`:

`erl --sname test1`
`>>node()`

In case you do have another name try with `net_adm:ping('test1@[full_name]')`.